# How to return specific item from Cloud Workflows instance?

Tags: json, yaml, conditional-statements, google-workflows

I have the problem to get the data out of the JSON response instance. I am using Cloud Workflows to get the information about the current state of my VMs. I am using the the `.get` functions that returns this long JSON that is high structured, e.g. `launchResult` is returned as:

```json
{
   "name":"some name",
   "status":"some status",
   "items":[
      {
         "key":"key1",
         "property1":"xxxx",
         "property2":"ccvdvdvd"
      },
      {
         "key":"key2",
         "property1":"xxxrerex",
         "property2":"ccvdveedvd"
      }
   ],
   "kind":"some kind"
}
```

I can return for example "some status", by `${launchResult.status}`,
even `key1`, as `{launchResult.items[0].key}`.

The question is: How can I do sth like `launchResult.items["key" == "key1"].property1`? I mean I want to return the `property1` from the item based on the key.

Comment: Did you had a chance to have a look on my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70207049/13171940)?

Comment: note that for loops will make this easier: https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax/iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the property from an item in an list of maps based on the value of another property of that map, I would suggest the following:

- To iterate over the elements of the list until you get the one with the property you're looking for.

This is a sample code I made to show [how to use iterations](http://glaforge.appspot.com/article/day-12-with-cloud-workflows-loops-and-iterations) along with [conditionals](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax/conditions) in [Cloud Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/apis) to achieve this:

```yaml
main:
  params: []
  steps:
  - define:
      assign:
        # Incremental variable set to zero
        - i: 0
        # Value to look up in list
        - cond: "key2"
        # A variable that contains a sample data as the JSON
        # showed in the question
        - test: 
            name: some name
            status: some status
            items:
            - key: "key1"
              property1: xxxx
              property2: ccvdvdvd
            - key: "key2"
              property1: xxxrerex
              property2: ccvdveedvd
            - key: "key3"
              property1: xxex
              property2: ccvdvffdvd
            kind: some kind
  - lookupInItems:
      switch:
        # Here we're looking for the element over the list test.items until the condition is met 
        # or the list ends
        - condition: ${i < len(test.items) and test.items[i].key!=cond}
        # If the condition is not met, keep iterating using iterate step
          next: iterate
      # If the element is found or the list ends, jumps to the read step
      next: read
  - iterate:
      assign: 
      # Increment the increment variable i
        - i: ${i+1}
      next: lookupInItems
  # If the iteration ends, check for the value
  - read:
      switch:
        # Check if the value was found
        # if this check is not made, an out of index error will occur when trying to show
        # the property of a value does not exists
        - condition: ${i < len(test.items)}
          next: found
      next: notfound
  # Print a message on the sys.log either the value was found or not
  - notfound:
      call: sys.log
      args:
        text: ${"Value " + cond + " not found in list"}
        severity: "WARNING"
      next: end
  - found:
      call: sys.log
      args:
        text: ${test.items[i].property1}
        severity: "INFO"
      next: end
```

See also:

- [Day 6 with Workflows — Arrays and dictionaries](http://glaforge.appspot.com/article/day-6-with-cloud-workflows-arrays-and-dictionaries)